# Increase line width in Plotly Scattergeo

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have a set of coordinates and I want to use them to draw a path on a map using Plotly. But I don't understand how to increase the width of the lines.

What I've tried:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
route_color = 'rgb(217, 20, 72)'

longitudes = [-77.00564, -79.15038, -81.08402, -82.67442, -84.26057]
latitudes = [38.89845, 37.47481, 35.24833, 34.80409, 33.91728]

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
    locationmode = 'USA-states',
    lon = longitudes,
    lat = latitudes,
    mode = 'lines',
    marker = dict(
        size = 15,
        color = route_color,
    )))

fig.show()
```

No matter if I put in `1` or `15` or `150` as `size` attribute, the width of the line stays the same. I started using the example code [from here](https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-maps/#us-flight-paths-map). I have the feeling that I just misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that you're trying to adjust the line width using the `marker` attribute, which is meant for points (or markers) on the plot, not for lines.

To adjust the width of the line in a Scattergeo trace, you should use the `line` attribute.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
route_color = 'rgb(217, 20, 72)'

longitudes = [-77.00564, -79.15038, -81.08402, -82.67442, -84.26057]
latitudes = [38.89845, 37.47481, 35.24833, 34.80409, 33.91728]

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
    locationmode = 'USA-states',
    lon = longitudes,
    lat = latitudes,
    mode = 'lines',
    line = dict(
        width = 4,  # Adjust this value to change the line width
        color = route_color,
    )))

fig.show()
```

Comment: In the example from plotly.com that I used (link in question) they put the `line` dict inside the `marker` dict, so I tried that as well (and it didn't work). Placing the `line` dict right into the `Scattergeo` constructor as you described did the job - thank you!